# Regex to extract the username from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a string **name** that can include the following possiblities and I wish to use a regex expression to remove that X part of the string with its corresponding underscore and obtain the filename only.

Possibilities of string **name**:

1. XXX_XXX_filename
2. XXX_filename

kindly note that X is an uppercase and consists of alphabets {A-Z} only. Can i have a regex that removes the X parts with the underscore as well?

Comment: `"XXX_XXX_filename".replace(/([A-Z]+_)+/g, '')`

Comment: Can `filename` have uppercase characters and/or `_`s?

Comment: Or you can just do `"XXX_XXX_filename".split('_').at(-1)`

Comment: filename can include any type of name(even numbers or underscore). I just need to remove the first three or six uppercase letters (username), which can be seperated by an underscore.

Comment: If you have a filename like `ABC_Joe`, and you have a string like `DEF_ABC_Joe`, how can you understand if the part to be removed is `DEF` or `DEF_ABC`?

Comment: Ok to make it simpler, a username is appended to a filename and the username can be of the format (XXX or XXX_XXX) as mentionned above. I just wish to extract the filename from that username_filename.

Comment: Like `(?:[A-Z]+_){1,2}` https://regex101.com/r/yd332L/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Correct! You can put your comment as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat 1 or 2 times matching 1 or more uppercase chars [A-Z] followed by an underscore.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
(?:[A-Z]+_){1,2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yd332L/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`"XXX_XXX_filename".replace(/^[A-Z_]*/g,"")`

If you know the number of total characters you can restrict the regexp a bit more:

`"XXX_XXX_filename".replace(/^[A-Z_]{3,7}/g,"")`

If you also know the total number of groups for upper case you could use this alos:

`"XXX_XXX_Filename".replace(/^([A-Z]+_?){0,2}/g,"")`

Comment: this would empty a string like `"XXX_XXX_FILENAME"`

Comment: You are correct, I've updated the answer with other options